# SSL XML Gateway - SSL Certificate Handshake Error

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on a website that exposes an xml gateway that clients can submit an xml request to and get an xml response in return.  The website/company has been purchased by a larger organization and has been migrated into their infrastructure.  The existing production site is using an ssl certificate by a particular certificate authority but the larger organization uses certificates issued by a different certificate authority.  We have tried run a test with one of their clients and they are getting an SSL handshake error.  The original developer says that the only way to get it to work is to restore the original SSL certificate and not to use the new ones.  I am looking for some guidance or direction to diagnose this issue, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the developer says, from the description is sensible to me, but the problem is theirs.

To verify that this is exactly what is happening you can do a wireshark capture and then decode the flow as `SSL`. If the problem is that the client do not trust the certificate send by the server and reject the connection you will see it in the handshake in the wireshark.

If you use a java client you could run it with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` to see the ssl messages from within java.

If this is indeed the problem then you must configure the client's truststore to have the certificate send by the server (which is the original one).

If this configuration is possible of course... This depends on the application

**UPDATE:**

Well if you migrated to a new CA, i.e. you deploy a new certificate in your interface, then sorry to say, it is "your" -meaning the server side- error.
IMHO, if it is possible, you should redeploy the old certificate for a prespecified period, communicating to all the stakeholders that you plan to migrate to a new certificate signed by a **new** CA, so that the clients don't break

Then it is their responsibility, within that period, to "fix" their client apps to be able to accept the new certificate. This can be as simple as configuration i.e. importing the certificate to a truststore, to as "complicated" as to change code and rebuild the client app (e.g. if the new issued certificate does not have extensions that the code is verifying or the CN has changed etc).

If it is not possible to redeploy the old certificate then, you just have to communicate the change to all stakeholders and then, they should "fix" it accordingly (as mentioned above)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I believe that it must be a trust issue between the client and the server.  Our issue is that the clients are independent organizations that work with the company and submit information.  We technically do not have access to configure their truststores.  What would you recommend in this case?

Comment: I am not clear on something.You work in the server side and you started using the new certificates and as a result the client's connection broke?How are the clients created?Via a `WSDL`?Are the clients java apps?

Comment: Let me clarify and provide more detail, we have a asp.net website that was originally developed using .net 1.1, this website simply has an aspx page that is receiving an xml request and is processing it and sending back an xml response to the calling client.  When I say client I mean a third party, could be another company that sends us information.  I am thinking that this could be related to what you mentioned about the client's truststore, the new certificate is probably going to have to be configured on each clients truststore.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly the route that we are going to take.